# Admob и фейковые клики

Tags: java, android, google-play, admob

Ситуация такая: как я знаю, за клики с одного устройства по рекламе - банят приложение за "фейковые клики", дело в том, что если кто-то захочет чтобы моё приложение заблокировали, он начнет кликать по рекламе очень много раз. Забанят ли меня или приложение в google play? 
Как этого можно избежать?

---

Нашел информацию:

[От гугл](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7062933?hl=ru&ref_topic=2745287)

[От хабрахабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/163339/)

Comment: В гугл плей ваc не забанят за недействительные клики, только в Admob.

Comment: @katso можно ли как-то обойти это?

Comment: Можете скрывать банер после клика. Если я не ошибаюсь, то сама документация по adMob рекомендует такой способ.